# Distributing an App to a large, but external membership without the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, distribution

I have a professional association client whose membership is well over 5000.  They are looking to us to adapt an App that we have developed commercially for distribution to their membership.  While they are looking to distribute to this group of users for free, they want to limit the distribution to just their membership.  Has anyone developed for this type of distribution where:

1) The App won't be distributed in house, per se
2) The number of users will far and away exceed 100
3) The IT department does not have control of the client devices
4) The clients are geographically dispersed and not inclined (understandable) to send in devices for installation - meaning that over the wire or over the air installation would be necessary.

I am looking for a definitive answer that meets these criteria and I will post my discovery and experiences for others to follow as this seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Why don't you distribute the app regularly through the App Store and simply implement a login screen when the app launches? This way only their users can use it.

Comment: The B2B Volume Purchasing Program (VPP) was designed by Apple for this purpose - limited distribution through the App Store. There are some hoops to jump through and your country must be supported.

Comment: Eli: The reluctance to use a login screen within the app is twofold: first, it means building a back end system to manage the users and passwords.  Second, the devices would need to be online in order for the app to successfully authenticate.

Comment: Robotic Cat: I am looking at the B2B option right now and will report finding here after.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well Apple does not allow this kind of distribution.

The Enterprise license will grant you the right to distribute the app your self, but only for employees of the registered company as an inhouse application.

You are stuck with the app store or distribution on jailbroke devices only.

There is no other way.